# ¿Cómo crear un módulo de documentación en OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

Necesitaria crear un modulo de documentación. Básicamente para que el usuario vaya al manual en caso de duda.

Pensaba en un formato html.

He visto en la ayuda de openxava la posibilidad de hacer un modulo de documentación:

https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/application_es.html#Aplicacion-Modulo+de+documentacion

Pero sólo funciona con Liferay o WebSphere Portal.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin usar Liferay o WebSphere Portal?

Answer (score 0):

Es verdad que los módulos de documentación están sólo disponibles dentro de un portal, sin embargo el sistema de ayuda funciona sin portal y creo que es justo lo que estás buscando. Se activa configurando unas propiedades en xava.properties.

Fíjate en la parte de Ayuda aquí:

https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/customizing_es.html#Personalizacion-Configuracion+de+propiedades+en+xava.properties

Algo así en xava.properties te podría servir:

```
helpAvailable=true
helpPrefix=ayuda/
```

Si la ayuda está en una carpeta ayuda dentro de tu aplicación. También lo puedes poner en otro servidor:

```
helpPrefix=https://www.example.com/ayuda
```

Si acaba con un subrayado puede tener suporte multiidioma, así:

```
helpPrefix=https://www.example.com/miaplicacion/ayuda_
```

Donde buscará por ayuda_en.html, ayuda_es.html o ayuda_ca.html, según el idioma del navegador